# Is it possible to reverse linux completely?

Tags: linux

For example, if you wanted to look at a computer through a mirror, it would be backwards. I was wondering if there was a feature where you could make it reversed so it would be backwards normally and you could read it normally in a mirror.

Comment: This needs a *lot* more clarification to fly here. What the heck are you talking about? :)

Comment: normally you can see a screen and read it easily. But when you look at it through a mirror, you would see it backwards. I was wondering if there was some way to reverse it so that it would be backwards normally and you can read it normally in a mirror. Does that help?

Comment: I assume you're talking about **mirroring your screen horizontally**? If so - [google has a ton of results](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+mirror+screen+horizontally) - but it's not so much *linux*, as your [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server)

Comment: @JordanJason you should edit your question and put the information you put in your comment in the question instead - at the moment the question doesn't have enough detail to be answered properly, and will likely be closed as a result

Comment: Ah. Ok. That makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xrandr is likely what you want. Some docs are available here: http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html#sect5

In the linked section you can see the `-x` and `-y` options which allow you to flip along the x and y axes.